# Clojure Factorials

Tags: clojure

```
(ns factorials)

(defn displayFactorials[number]
    (if (> number 1)
        (do
        (* number (displayFactorials(- number 1))))))

(defn -main []
    (println "To display the factorials,")
    (print " enter the number: ") (flush)
    (let
        [ number (double (read))]
        (println)
        (displayFactorials number)
        (println)
    )
)
```

I'm writing a factorial program that receives a user input.
The program is compiling, bu the result is not printing.
Any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it look like this:

```
(println (displayFactorials number))
```

Here is a better formatted version of the program:

```
(ns demo.core)

(defn displayFactorials
  [number]
  (if (> number 1)
    (* number (displayFactorials (- number 1)))))

(defn -main []
  (println "To display the factorials,")
  (print " enter the number: ") (flush)
  (let [number (double (read))]
    (println
      (displayFactorials number))))
```

---

Hint:  You also forgot about what to do if the number is equal to one.

---

**Update**

See the hint above.  Write a unit test in the file `test/tst/demo/core.clj` like:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.test))

(deftest dummy#
  (println :answer (displayFactorials 5)))
```

Try running `lein test` and see the exception:

```
ERROR in (dummy#) (Numbers.java:1068)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at clojure.lang.Numbers.ops (Numbers.java:1068)
    clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply (Numbers.java:173)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invokeStatic (core.clj:6)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invoke (core.clj:3)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invokeStatic (core.clj:6)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invoke (core.clj:3)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invokeStatic (core.clj:6)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invoke (core.clj:3)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invokeStatic (core.clj:6)
    demo.core$displayFactorials.invoke (core.clj:3)
    tst.demo.core$fn__18527.invokeStatic (core.clj:11)
    tst.demo.core/fn (core.clj:10)
```

that should be a *BIG* clue as to what is missing.

Comment: Hm... I"m getting a Execution error (NullPointerException) when I compile the edited program